# NLP: Identify whether given text is Query or Statement

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, chatbot

I am working on conversational chatbot.How to determine whether a given text is demanding an answer or is providing some information?

Case 1 : We are thinking of booking this hotel because it is close to the freedom trail.
Expected Result : Giving some info

Case 2: I would like to know the distance from Boston Logan airport to the hotel.
Expected Result : Question

Case 3:How far is Airport?
Expected Result : Question

I have dataset of 19k queries categorized as (Question and Not a Question).What is the best way/model to proceed now (Using Python)?

Comment: are you looking at something rule-based or to train a system to make this distinction? Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083060/determine-if-a-sentence-is-an-inquiry

Answer (score -1):

If I am not too late,

1. To identify a question or answer I have recently done this using fasttext. If you have big enough dataset, fasttext will give you best results with smallest model that can run on any machine.
2. To determine whether the statement is providing answer or not you have to build an NER(kind of thing) which will look for some specific things like phone numbers, emails, names etc for every message that is coming in.

[output with my model for your questions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3zF7.png)