# How to determine if a sentence is an instruction (imperative)?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-processing, syntaxnet

I would like to identify if a given sentence is imperative, ie it contains an instruction for someone to do something. Eg:

- (Please) (Would be great if you could) Send me the PDF I asked for
- (I request you to) (Please) Submit your resignation tomorrow

Specifically, I'm looking for an answer that is along the lines of: [How to find out if a sentence is a question (interrogative)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573872/how-to-find-out-if-a-sentence-is-a-question-interrogative)

Here, an SBARQ node containing an optional SQ node is indicative of a question (interrogative). Is there a similar way to check for imperative?

One idea I have is to check if the root node is a verb (VB, VBP, VBD, etc), but this may be too broad / incomplete? Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you find any resources or answers ?